# Why doesn't my Java code create a table in an in-memory SQLite database and print the table name?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc

I want to create an in-memory database and check that the table exists afterwards. Unfortunately, my code doesn't print anything to the console, so either the check for a table or the table creation process is wrong.

How do I fix it?

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main  {
    private static String url = "jdbc:sqlite::memory";

    private static void createNewTable(Connection conn) {

        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (\n"
        + " id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n"
        + " name text NOT NULL"
        + ");";

        try (Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();) {
            stmt.execute(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void checkTable(Connection conn){
        String sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type='table'";

        try (Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("table: " + rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn;
        try{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            createNewTable(conn);
            checkTable(conn);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you querying `sqlite_temp_master`? The created table is not a temporary one.

Comment: Try `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master ...` instead of `... FROM sqlite_temp_master ...`.